# Error loading packages in cross platform c# application

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, visual-studio-2017, restsharp

I offloaded a project which involved making a cross platform app from a website. My friend who was supposed to do the project, has given me a solution that contains a portable section and a droid section. The ios and windows apps will be made once i complete the remaining portions of the portable code.

Now, he used some packages that are failing to load completely on my system. He had compiled an apk from this code, so this code must be working, but I cannot resolve the issues with the packages. I removed the packages directory from the project he supplied to me, and rebuilt the project hoping the packages would restore themselves correctly. But I ended up with the same errors again.

Then I found that "Mono.Android" and "RestSharp" were marked with warning signs under the references list. So I removed these two, and tried installing them fresh from Nuget Package Manager. Trying to install RestSharp gave me the following error:

```
Could not install package 'RestSharp 104.5.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

And I also cannot find "Mono.Android" package in the Nuget Package Manager. My friend was unable to help me out on this. Please suggest how to get this project working.

Thanks in advance.

Debopam Parua

Comment: RestSharp does not support the current PCL profile you are using.  You need to talk to RestSharp about this.

Comment: Pardon me, I don'e know how this works. But what exactly is a PCL profile and how can I change it for the current project?

Comment: change the supported platforms in the pcl project properties